# Template binding on ContentPresenter not working

Tags: wpf, binding, alignment, contentpresenter

I'm writing a custom button:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSinergoHMIControls.RoundedButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSinergoHMIControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Click="button_Click" PreviewMouseDown="Button_MouseDown" PreviewMouseUp="Button_MouseUp">
            <Button.Resources>

            </Button.Resources>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Width="{Binding Size}"
                            Height="{Binding Size}"
                            BorderBrush="#FF3C7FB1"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Name="RoundedButtonBorder">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#3a4451" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#0b2039" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

and I'm trying to bind 'HorizontalAlignement' and 'VerticalAlignment' of the ContentPresenter to the template. What I would like to do, then, is to use the button like this:

```
<local:RoundedButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="73" Margin="35,10,282,236" FontSize="30"  Width="200" Content="Hello" Foreground="Red"/>
```

And having the text inside the button being centered in both axis. This doesn't work and I cannot figure out the reason. What do I miss in my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem.

In the tag 'Button' I had to add:

```
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
```

Otherwise it seems that the binding is not "propagated" to the inner elements.

That was the issue!

Comment: Why do you have all the nested templates?